Apply different customized indicator for different tickers in tradingview
I have created 2 customized indexes-indicators one for big 4 techs and other for 4 big banks. I would like to be able to tell trandingview which one to use depending on the working-ticker displayed.
this is indicator-index.1, named "Tech_idx" (big tech):
indicator(title = "Big.tech", shorttitle = "BigTech", overlay = false)

sec_1_t =  request.security("NASDAQ:AAPL", timeframe.period, close) 
sec_2_t =  request.security("NASDAQ:MSFT", timeframe.period, close)
sec_3_t =  request.security("NASDAQ:GOOGL", timeframe.period, close) 
sec_4_t =  request.security("NASDAQ:AMZN", timeframe.period, close) 

Tech_idx = sec_1_t*0.25+sec_2_t*0.25+sec_3_t*0.25+sec_4_t*0.25

plot(Tech_idx, title="Tech_i", color=color.blue)

now this is indicator-index.2, named "Bank_idx", (big four banks):
indicator(title = "Big.Banks", shorttitle = "BigBanks", overlay = false)

sec_1_b =  request.security("NYSE:JPM", timeframe.period, close) 
sec_2_b =  request.security("NYSE:BAC", timeframe.period, close)
sec_3_b =  request.security("NYSE:WFC", timeframe.period, close) 
sec_4_b =  request.security("NYSE:GS", timeframe.period, close) 

Bank_idx = sec_1_b*0.25+sec_2_b*0.25+sec_3_b*0.25+sec_4_b*0.25

plot(Bank_idx, title="Bank_i", color=color.blue)

Now i would like to be able to tell tradingview that if "JPM" (JPMorgan) is the working-ticker, then bring "Bank_idx" as the indicator to display, but if "AAPL" (APPLE) is the working-ticker, then bring "Tech_idx" as the indicator to display , otherwise Null.
This formula which works for SECURITIES does not work for INDICATORS (which is the case):
ticker = syminfo.ticker
var string b = 

ticker == "JPM" ? "XLF" : 
ticker == "AAPL" ? "XLK" : 

NULL

secB = request.security(b, timeframe.period, close) 

plot(secB, title="b", color=color.blue)


I would appreciate help from experts. thanks and kind regards
